# Git rebase --abort, restore

Tags: git, git-rebase, abort

This happened because git rebase was used without understanding

I ran git rebase, and made some changes, then I ran the "git rebase --abort" command and the changes were deleted,
How can I restore these changes, I committed them

Comment: If you committed something then you should be able to find them in `git reflog`.

Comment: When rebase is working, at least some of the operations, items are being added to the reflog.... so you might go back to the last commit that the rebase was able to work on but then you have to figure out all the other things that were pending to be rebased so that you can set it up again and avoid having to redo some of the work. No silver bullet, sorry.

Comment: Let me add an answer so I can tell you how to be able to resume it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... suppose that you were running a rebase like this:

```
git rebase discard-this rebase-this --onto some-branch
```

And you, at some point, ran `git rebase --abort` and now you would like to resume the rebase there. There is no way to ask rebase to resume from the old rebase operation.... what you can do is ask rebase to *manually* start from the point where you aborted.... *and* for the sake of simplicity, I assume you were rebasing a straight branch.

So... check `git reflog` and find the last commit that rebase was able to generate before you aborted. Let's say that this commit (the product of rebase as it is showing up in `git reflog`) is `X-rebased`. Then, go to the original branch and find the original commit equivalent to `X-rebased` and let's call it `X-orig`. Now, in order to continue with the rebase, you should run this:

```
git rebase X-orig rebase-this --onto X-rebased
```

That should work.